# Adding 1KM grids to Folium map

Tags: python, maps, folium

Could someone suggest a way to adding 1KM wide grids/graticules to folium map? The folium example here uses lat/longitude intervals but doesn't render the grid.

```py
import folium

# Bangkok coordinates
center_lat = 13.7563
center_lon = 100.4911

m = folium.Map(location=[center_lat, center_lon], zoom_start=11)


# Interval in degrees (1 kilometer ≈ 0.00694444 degrees)
interval = 0.00694444

# Create grid lines
grid_lines = []

# East-west lines (from -90 to 90 latitude)
for lat in range(-90, 91, int(1 / interval)):
  west_point = (-180, lat)
  east_point = (180, lat)
  grid_lines.append(folium.PolyLine([west_point, east_point], color="black", weight=0.5, opacity=0.5))

# North-south lines (from -180 to 180 longitude)
for lon in range(-180, 181, int(1 / interval)):
  south_point = (lon, -90)
  north_point = (lon, 90)
  grid_lines.append(folium.PolyLine([south_point, north_point], color="black", weight=0.5, opacity=0.5))

# Add lines to the map
for line in grid_lines:
  line.add_to(m)

# Display the map
m
```

Answer (score 1):

Your grid *does* actually render on the [map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLfu8.png) but it's not as you expect because you're using [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) instead of [`numpy.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html). Also you're inverting the locations of each [`PolyLine`](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/latest/reference.html#folium.vector_layers.PolyLine) in your two for-loops. So, here is one possible fix :

```
import folium
import numpy as np

CLAT, CLON = 13.7563, 100.4911

m = folium.Map(location=[CLAT, CLON], zoom_start=11)

INTERVAL = 1 / 111  # 1 km to degrees, gives ~0.009

LINE_STYLE = {"color": "black", "weight": 0.5, "opacity": 0.5}

def add_gl(m, s, e, hztl, **kwargs):
    for v in np.arange(s, e + 1, INTERVAL):
        coords = [[v, -180], [v, 180]] if hztl else [[-90, v], [90, v]]
        folium.PolyLine(coords, **kwargs).add_to(m)

add_gl(m, -90, 90, True, **LINE_STYLE)
add_gl(m, -180, 180, False, **LINE_STYLE)
```

***NB** : It took ~40 seconds for the map to display on my JupyterLab and the navigation is relatively cumbersome/slow. So, if performance is a concern, you may need to reduce the interval :*

```
INTERVAL = 10 / 111  # 10 kms instead of 1km

# with this, the map takes ~2-5s to render
```

Output (`m`):

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Timeless. Perhaps if you limit the gird to maximum 10 KMs or to current longitude. latitude it might improve the performance?

Comment: You're welcome ;). Yes, with *10 kms*, the map takes ~5 sec to display 
on my jupyter and the navigation is much smoother.

Comment: Great, Could you please update the code snippet so others could benefit from it as well. Thanks again.

Comment: I updated the answer to include that as a note ;)